# ¿Cómo puedo conservar el formato de un dato obtenido con la función VLookup()?

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo una hoja con datos en distintos formatos (fechas, decimales, texto, etc.).

Busco un valor (`my_index`) en un rango (`lookup_range`) y quiero recuperar el dato para escribirlo en una celda de otra hoja.

La macro funciona bien, pero cuando el valor que recupero por la función `VLookup` es una fecha y la copio a la otra hoja, pierde su formato.

```
Dim lookup_range As Range
Dim my_index, my_value As Variant

my_value = Application.VLookup(my_index, lookup_range, num_col, False)
Sheets(3).Cells(num_row, last_col_s1 + num_col - 1).Value = my_value
```

Por eso, cuando el dato en `lookup_range` es `02/05/2015`, el dato copiado en la `Hoja 3` se muestra como si fuera el número `41761`.

Necesito conservar el formato original que tiene el valor en la `Hoja 1` al ser copiado a la `Hoja 3`.

Comment: ¿Todas las posibles respuestas tienen el mismo formato? Es decir, ¿toda la columna "num_col" dentro de lookup_range tiene el mismo formato?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las funciones "nativas" como `vlookup()` de Excel devuelven valores o información sobre una celda pero no ambos.

La alternativa es utilizar copiar y pegar o bien copiar y pegar especial en alguna de sus variantes. A continuación un ejemplo de copiar y pegar.

```
Sub ConservarFormato()
    Dim rgOrigen As Range, rgDestino As Range
    ActiveSheet.Activate
    Set rgOrigen = Range("B1")
    Set rgDestino = Range("F2")
    rgOrigen.Copy Destination:=rgDestino
End Sub
```

Comment: Creo que tu respuesta no cubre el hecho de que es un lookup. Para Copiar y pegar, debieras saber en qué celda específica está la respuesta que buscas.

Comment: @jachguate: mi respuesta cubre el hecho de que es un lookup en el primer párrafo. El código que incluí es para un caso generalizado suficientemente sencillo que la hace fácilmente adoptable y adaptable y me parece que así es de mayor utilidad para los que saben lo básico de VBA para Excel.